# Can't get edit route to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't get the routes right to edit users.

Below are `_header.html.erb`, which has edit users link:

```
<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
```

and `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'help'  => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy' 

  get '/all_users', :to => 'users#index'

  get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user

  resources :users do
    get user
  end

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
end
```

**EDIT**

I added

```
get 'edit' => 'static_pages#edit'
```

and now there is the same problem but it says there is a `UrlGenerationError`.

Comment: If none of the answers below helped you, I'd recommend updating the question and adding the whole error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
get '/all_users', :to => 'users#index'

get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user

get user
end
```

And use:

```
resources :users do
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
end
```

Which will give you:

```
 edit_user_account_activation GET    /users/:user_id/account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)     account_activations#edit
                        users GET    /users(.:format)                                           users#index
                              POST   /users(.:format)                                           users#create
                     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                       users#new
                    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                  users#edit
                         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#show
                              PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#update
                              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#update
                              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make routes like this:

```
> resources :users do
//extra routes goes here if you want to make out of it
end
```

Run `rake routes` or `bundle exec rake routes` in rails console to see the generated routes.